# Generic types with point-free functions

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typescript-generics, pointfree

Supose I have next funcion:

```
function cast<T>(v: any): T {
    return v as T;
}
```

Now, I have an array what I want to cast using map:

```
const arr = [1, 3, 5];

// works
arr.map(value => cast<number>(value));

// but I want
arr.map(cast<number>);
```

Is it possible? Can I pass generic on point-free map?

Comment: Hi Dabbbb. I tried your example in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/, and the second variation doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the method `map` from the *Array prototype* is generic.

```
Array<T>.map<U>(callback: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U): U[]
```

So, by using your `cast` function with any type argument (like using it as a pointer-free) returns `unknown`. Totally expected.

You can cast your *array* like so

```
const arr = [1, 3, 5];
const re = arr.map<string>(cast);
```

[Here](https://codewithstyle.info/TypeScript-3-4-hidden-gem-propagated-generic-type-arguments/) is an interesting post about this.

---

I was reading this post months later and another idea just flashed in my mind.
Another solution could be a function wrapper to pass the type argument to the `cast` function explicitly.

```
type Fn<T> = (element: any) => T;

const cast = <T>(element: any): T => {
    return element as T;
}

const caster = <T>() => {
    return cast as Fn<T>;
}

const dut: any[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const casted = dut.map(caster<number>());

// casted is of type number[]
```

Although the main solution is still the best, this approach can solve some situations where the target API does not offer any overload to infer the type.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible as `cast<number>` is not considered as a callback function which is required by array map.

You can try to see what is and isn’t a function by simply logging them in console.

Try `console.log(cast)`
And `console.log(cast<number>)`

Answer (score 0):

A bit more type-safe alternative ([Fail-Fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) run-time checks) using point-free style:

```js
function assert(expr: unknown, msg = ""): asserts expr { if (!expr) throw Error(msg); }
const every = <T>(cb: (t: unknown) => t is T) => (a: unknown[]): a is T[] => arr.every(cb);
const isNumber = (mn: unknown): mn is number => typeof mn === "number"

const arr: unknown[] = ... // given some unknown array
assert(every(isNumber)(arr));
arr // arr now of type number[] (or has thrown, which could be fetched by an error handler)
```

[Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM6oKYCcoAoMAeADlgFyLgDWYcA7mADSIC2qA5ogLyIBEPAlOTSYcqRIRKIA3ohjBEuAIQSs-RFAAWWOogCiWbVlys2-ANyIAvgFgAUBASoo4gG7YAnl0QAeACoA+XAgAI3JcKHIqGno1Tn91WTFfWPjcZANyLAxkABMEABtPKLowAG0AXUEUA0TEXwquePSsADoMNyx3IODzOwcwJ0SAORBmYOwvYzBIsGoSquYkGDEwUfGsRvV3Igw4eUWuTm4eVbHsHjs7HIwIfPSMRH7B5pm5+gaAeg-ENhg3JFQcGYD2K9GqWGQ7jswmweHaHlwyxGZ1UaQM-F6tmaiC+4MQ0Vqey2O3xa2wDVwcA2GjQ6i0JSYtA0MAgGkecBA+RyiHGiGAGCgrIw3OCnmQSGwhkQNLAOXy2H4QA)